# Replace vaue in column depending on another column in dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, refactoring, factors

Hello I have a dataframe such as

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 
A    nan  NaN 
B    ET1  Carnivora
C    ET1  NaN 
D    ET2  Fish
E    OK   Aves 
F    ET3  NaN
```

and I have a **list**

```
List_ET<-c("ET1","ET2","ET3","nan")
```

And I would like to replace all df$COL3 values if the corresponding `df$COL2` is present in that list by `Unknown` but if`df$COL3` is not `NaN`, I do nothing.

than I should get :

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 
A    nan  Unknown 
B    ET1  Carnivora
C    ET1  Unknown 
D    ET2  Fish
E    OK   Aves 
F    ET3  Unknown
```

Here is the dataframe

```
structure(list(COL1 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), COL2 = structure(c(4L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("ET1", "ET2", "ET3", "nan", "OK"), class = "factor"), 
    COL3 = structure(c(4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("Aves", 
    "Carnivora", "Fish", "NaN"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

So far I tried

```
df$COL3[df$COL2 %in% List_ET]<- "Unknown"
```

But it does not included to do nothing when df$COL3 is not `NaN`

Comment: I thought to use : ```df$COL3[df$COL2 %in% List_ET & !is.na(df$COL3)]<- "Unknown"  ``` but it does not seem to work

Comment: in the data you provided COL3 has no NAs. "NaN" is a character in your data.

Comment: Also, what you wrote doesnt work properly because both COL2 and COL3 are factors instead of characters

Comment: Yes I known that, that's why I need a solution

Comment: Since you are working with factors, you have to modify levels first.  See the answer proposed.  Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
perhaps you may be looking for this loop

```
levels(df$COL3) <- c("Aves", "Carnivora", "Fish", "NaN", "Unknown")

for(i in seq_along(df$COL3)){
  if(df$COL2[i] %in% List_ET & df$COL3[i] == "NaN"){
    df$COL3[i] <- "Unknown"
  }
}

> df
  COL1 COL2      COL3
1    A  nan   Unknown
2    B  ET1 Carnivora
3    C  ET1   Unknown
4    D  ET2      Fish
5    E   OK      Aves
6    F  ET3   Unknown
```

But if just want to replace `NaN` in col3 with `"Unknown"` use this simply

```
levels(df$COL3) <- c("Aves", "Carnivora", "Fish", "Unknown")

> df$COL3
[1] Unknown   Carnivora Unknown   Fish      Aves      Unknown  
Levels: Aves Carnivora Fish Unknown

#OR
> df
  COL1 COL2      COL3
1    A  nan   Unknown
2    B  ET1 Carnivora
3    C  ET1   Unknown
4    D  ET2      Fish
5    E   OK      Aves
6    F  ET3   Unknown
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need `type.convert` over `df` and then use `ifelse`, e.g.,

```
within(
  type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE),
  COL3 <- ifelse(COL2 %in% List_ET & COL3 == "NaN", "Unknown", COL3)
)
```

which gives

```
  COL1 COL2      COL3
1    A  nan   Unknown
2    B  ET1 Carnivora
3    C  ET1   Unknown
4    D  ET2      Fish
5    E   OK      Aves
6    F  ET3   Unknown
```